# Difference in initializing char-array and char with integer literals

Tags: c++, arrays, char, initialization, compiler-warnings

On my system (*4.13.11-1-ARCH, gcc 7.2.0*) `char` is `signed`. When initializing an array of `char` with an `integer literal` like this:

```
const char mydata[] = {
    0x80
};
```

I get the following error:

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘128’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

However, when I instead do `const char data = 0x80` the compiler is not worried of any narrowing, although it happens of course. The output is `7F`, the highest positive `signed char` value.

## Question

Why is the compiler not equally worried about truncation in both cases?

Comment: Don't you think when you ask about a compiler behavior it would be helpful to mention which one you are using?

Comment: @Slava afaik narrowing conversions inside `{}` should be disallowed on any compiler

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization basically when you use list initialisation it is more strict and compiler will complain

Comment: @tobi303 we do not know that yet, so when you ask "why compiler does that or does not do this" it would not hurt to say which one.

Comment: @Slava errors in general should not depend on compiler but on the version of the standard. Nevermind, I get your point

Comment: @Slava I've added the compiler version.

Comment: @Marcus yes I see that, thanks

Comment: `char` is never interpreted as `signed char`. `char` and `signed char` are always distinct types. They may or may not have the same representation.

Comment: `const char mydata[] = { 0x80 };` does not create or initialize a `char*`. It creates and initializes an array object of type `const char[2]`. Arrays are not pointers. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); most of it applies to C++ as well.

Comment: This question is answered by reading the error message carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initializer of the form `const char c = 0x80` is a much older construct than 
initializer lists, which have been introduced later. So it was possible to define stricter rules for initializer lists, while these rules where not applied to "older" initializers (probably because of not to break "older" code more than necessary).

Hence, initializer lists as defined in [this online c++ standard draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#2) forbid such narrowing:

> **8.5.1 Aggregates**
>
> (2) When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as
>   specified in [dcl.init.list], the elements of the initializer list are
>   taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing
>   subscript or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause. **If the initializer-clause is an
>   expression and a narrowing conversion ([dcl.init.list]) is required to
>   convert the expression, the program is ill-formed.** ...

BTW: If you use a brace initializer like `const char data { 0x80 }`, you will get an error, too. So the stricter rules are due to brace-initializers / initializer lists, and not due to whether you initialize an array or a scalar value.

Comment: `const char data = 0x80` *could* produce the same warning, it's just not required.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: but with `const char data = 0x80`, the program is not ill-formed, while with `const char data { 0x80 }` it is, right?

Comment: I believe so (but I know C better than I know C++).

Answer (score 5):

This is actually one of the reasons why `{}` initialization should be prefered: It does not allow narrowing conversions. In contrast to this, the old way of initalization (as in `const char data = 0x80`) does allow narrowing conversions.